# Laravel - Jquery , Ajax - Inserting Nullable Data as an array in the database

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I am trying to insert 2 files `image` and `video` and addditional image which is an array for now I can insert both, but when I try to add another image as an array and save it, the output is also inserting the video which is chose on the form. how can i save the array of images into an independent images and remove the video which is automatically inserted

here is my **UI** please take a look my page which I save it as image and vide and adding images again

[image]

and here is my database output

here what I want the output is the greenlight and yellowlight should be single and has ***No Video Inserted*** to it as on the page they are only array and not connected to the video
[image]

now here is my **Controller Code**

```
  $this->validate($request, [
        'paxsafety_image.*' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
        'paxsafety_video.*' => 'nullable|mimes:mp4,mov,ogg | max:20000'
    ]);
    $paxSafety = [];
    $paxSafetyVideo = [];
    if ($request->has('paxsafety_image') && $request->has('paxsafety_video'))
    {   
        //Handle File Upload


        foreach ($request->file('paxsafety_image') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/paxsafety_folder',$fileNameToStore);
            array_push($paxSafety, $fileNameToStore);
        }



        foreach ($request->file('paxsafety_video') as $key => $file)
        {
            // Get FileName
            $filenameWithExt2 = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            //Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo( $filenameWithExt2, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            //Get just extension
            $extension2 = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //Filename to Store
            $fileNameToStore2 = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension2;
            //Upload Image
            $path = $file->storeAs('public/paxsafety_folder',$fileNameToStore2);
            array_push($paxSafetyVideo, $fileNameToStore2);
        }


        $fileNameToStore = serialize($paxSafety);
        $fileNameToStore2 = serialize($paxSafetyVideo);
    }
    else
    {
        $paxSafety[] = 'noimage.jpg';
        $paxSafetyVideo[] = 'noimage.jpg';
    }


    foreach ($paxSafety as $key => $value) {
        $paxSafetyContent = new PaxSafety;
        $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_image = $value;
        foreach ($paxSafetyVideo as $key => $values) {
        $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_video = $values;
        }
        $paxSafetyContent->save();
    }
```

and here is my ***View Code***

```
 {{ Form::file('paxsafety_image[]') }} &nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>  <span class="fa fa-camera"></span> Upload Image&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong>

 {{ Form::file('paxsafety_video[]') }} &nbsp;&nbsp; <strong>  <span class="fa fa-video-camera"></span> Upload Video&nbsp;&nbsp; </strong>
```

my ***Script Code***

```
 <script>  
        $(document).ready(function(){  
             var i=1;  
             $('#add').click(function(){  
                  i++;  
                  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><th>Upload new Image</th><td>{{ Form::file('paxsafety_image[]') }} <button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove fa fa-minus-circle"></button></td></tr>');  
             });  
             $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
                  var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
                  $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
             });  
             $('#submit').click(function(){  
            var form = $('#add_name')[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);

              $.ajax({   
                   method:"POST",  
                   data:formData,  
                   success:function(data)  
                   {  
                        alert(data);  
                        $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                   }  
              });  
         });

        });  
 </script>
```

also, here is my table schema

```
  $table->string('paxsafety_image')->nullable();
  $table->string('paxsafety_video')->nullable();
```

Comment: is your `upload new image and video` section select single `image` and `video` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Wrong Part Is Here

```
foreach ($paxSafety as $key => $value) {
    $paxSafetyContent = new PaxSafety;
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_image = $value;
  /*** 
   foreach ($paxSafetyVideo as $key => $values) {
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_video = $values;
    }
  **/
    $paxSafetyContent->save();
}
```

you are inserting the video in everytime you create new PaxSafety
if you are sure you have only one video attached the first image you can do this

```
foreach ($paxSafety as $key => $value) {
    $paxSafetyContent = new PaxSafety;
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_image = $value;
   /** if it's the first image && the first video exists insert the first video **/
   if($key == 0 && isset($paxSafetyVideo[$key]) && $paxSafetyVideo[$key]){
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_video = $paxSafetyVideo[$key];
    }

    $paxSafetyContent->save();
}
```

or you can do this if you wanted to attach a video with multiple images in the future

```
foreach ($paxSafety as $key => $value) {
    $paxSafetyContent = new PaxSafety;
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_image = $value;
   /** if a video with the current image index exists insert the video value **/
   if(isset($paxSafetyVideo[$key]) && $paxSafetyVideo[$key]){
    $paxSafetyContent->paxsafety_video = $paxSafetyVideo[$key];
    }

    $paxSafetyContent->save();
}
```